# Batch execution error "not recognised as an internal or external command"

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch, xcopy

`D:\temp\copyTXT.bat` is a simple script containing:

```
XCOPY /v D:\temp\MyFile.txt D:\Documents\
```

- Executing the script fails, flashing a window for ~100ms, then does nothing *(no copy at all)*, but if I call the batch file from a terminal, it errors with:

  ```
  X is not recognized as an internal or external command...
  ```
- If I run the command itself from a terminal, it performs as intended

Some think it could be a question of rights or a badly defined path:

- I am using an Administrator account and verified `%PATH%` includes `C:\Windows\System32`
- I've copied `XCOPY.exe` to `D:\temp\` to make sure, and am executing the batch file from within `D:\temp`
- I can run the same exact batch file on another computer running the same Windows 7 OS

What am I doing wrong? Why does the batch file fail, yet I can execute the command directly with no problem?

Comment: Try doing a new batch file with the same command (run the command in CMD and then copy it from there and paste it in the batch file. (I suspect that there's some invisible character there in the batch file.)

Comment: Your command is valid on Windows 7.  As suggested it's likely there's something wrong with your .BAT file.

Comment: How did you make the batch file, exactly? Could you upload it e.g. on [ge.tt](http://ge.tt/)? Did the error message say `X is not recognized etc.` instead of `XCOPY`? I tried replicating the issue by putting one LF character (thus omitting the CR) between `X` and `COPY`. Editors like Notepad would show everything on one line, which can be copy-pasted on the command prompt, running just fine. Starting the `.bat` would give a `X is not recognized` error and the `COPY` command would run instead. By saving as UTF-8 with BOM the batch would return `╗┐XCOPY is not etc.`  Not quite like yours, still.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a ZWS (Invisible character) between the `X` and the `COPY` just rewrite the command yourself without any ZWS that would probably fix it.